# Can the C++ Keywords be used with just only the iostream include directive? What else is there besides keywords that can be used with only iostream?

Tags: c++, iostream

I consider myself a **C++ beginner** and have come to a question when dreading the fact of using many **include directives**. So instead of figuring it out myself the long way, I have come to get some help before I can learn and practice more.

From the book **Absolute C++ 5th edition by Walter Savitch**, says that "The operator sizeof is part of the core C++ Language and requires no include directive or using directive."  *12.4 Random Access to Files, page 585*

I want to know where can I find other operators or codes that does not use the include directive or using directive.

This could help me build programs before I can start learning more of the C++ Libraries.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking for the [c++ keywords](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword)?

Comment: Maybe, does the C++ keywords require no include directives?

Comment: You're approaching this the wrong way. Learning C++ is learning the Standard Library. Heck, learning any language is learning its core library.

Comment: The keywords are built into the language, they are not part of the standard library as such but your question is way broad and essentially you're asking for off-site resources

Comment: @rubenvb exactly that is what I want to do, learn its core library.

Comment: Then you'll need to include Standard Library headers, because that's how c++ works.

Comment: @Samir C++'s design is split between the *core language* (the syntax, keywords, and their behaviour) and the *standard library*. You will go nowhere with only the core language if your goal is to learn idiomatic C++, because that's only one third of the story.

Comment: If you want a subset of the standard library that enable you to make non-trivial practice programs, I'd personally suggest `<iostream>` (text I/O), `<vector>` (the default-choice container, which is a  growable array), `<memory>` (for dynamic allocation) and `<algorithm>` (reusable algorithms such as sorting, partitioning, etc). Edit: and `<string>` ! Forgot it :p

Comment: my goal is to master C++ :D I understand that there is more to C++ than just the keywords, just wanted to know what were the features that require no include directives. I think EdChum answered my question.

Comment: What you're looking for is here: [C++ language](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking about can all be answered by going on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/). Basically there are many default libraries that can be included by writing `#include <lib>`. So for example you want to use vectors (well optimized dynamic array), you write `#include <vector>`, if you want to handle input and output you write `#include <iostream>`, etc.

All of this can be found documented on page I've linked above. If you don't know with what to start some basic and most libraries would be iostream, string, vector, map.
Then there is an memory library, which provides for example an unique pointer which is a really strong tool in C++.
Then there is an algorithm library, containing useful functions working with containers over iterators.
These are just examples that came to my mind first and I've used them the most. If you are not sure about anything you can always search on cppreference for full documentation on it.

If you have any other or more specific question feel free to ask.